# How to save any text in capital letter entered by user in the form , user have access to enter any way?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, php-5.6

Here is the input field where the user is entering the data:

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname_field" class="input-text required-entry"
       placeholder="<?php echo $this->__("Enter your nickname") ?>"
       value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getNickname()) ?>" />
```

I want to save the data in capital form in the Magento back end.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller file you have to write this before save :

```
$data->setNickname(strtoupper($data->getNickname()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery("#fname").keyup(function(){

           //var getfname = jQuery("#fname").val();     

           this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();

        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve this data in a controller ( with some `$nickname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('nickname');` for example), you can just use the [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) method.

```
$nickname = strtoupper($nickname)
```